# Purpose of .all(0 when deleting outliers unclear

Tags: python, outliers

**Problem:**
I am trying to delete rows with outliers in a DataFrame with over 20 variables and 6000 rows.
**Current Approach:** Excluding rows with values that are > 3 times the Standard Deviation.

**Question:** I have found this code in a tutorial to exclude the upper outliers :

```
econ_df = econ_df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(econ_df)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

but the purpose of .all() is unclear to me in this context. Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's testing if the entire row (because axis=1 was passed) is `True` from the result of the absolute value of `zscore`